# How to store extended access token globally?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to store extentAT variable globally for further graph API calls. Kindly help me in storing this variable. Here is my code sample

```
FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) 
           {
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                alert(accessToken);
                appid="xxxxxxxxxx";
                appsecret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
                var exchangeUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token="+accessToken+"&client_id="+appid+"&client_secret="+appsecret;
                        //got the accesstoken with 1-2 hours expire time
                $.ajax({  
                  type: "GET",
                  url: exchangeUrl,  
                  success: function(data)
                  { 
                     extended = data.split('=');
                     extendedAT = extended['1'].replace('&expires','');
                         alert(extendedAT);
                         // return extendedAT;
                         // $('#AccessToken').val(extendedAT);
                         // $user_session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('fbuser');
                // $user_session->access_token = $paramsfb['access_token'];
                  }

                  });
} else 
            {
             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
         },{scope: 'email,user_photos,user_videos,offline_access'});

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use session to store value and get it as where it required. 
This is the reference link for jQuery session.

https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin

just store value in session like:

```
$.session.set("extendedAT", extendedAT);
```

and get it where you want to again using:

```
$.session.get('extendedAT');
```

I am using it. Hope help you.

Also I will happy if any new idea posted here for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the declaration of the `extendedAT` variable outside the function:

```
var extendedAT = "";

FB.login(function(response) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: i do this but cant get values in graphapi call